# Invalidate element in list view row does not work

Tags: android, textview

I am using `CursorAdapter` to populate a list. One of the views inside list item (`TextView`, with its height set to `WRAP_CONTENT`) is used to display text messages with a different font size, i.e. some list items will have text 12 sp big while others will be 16 sp.

The problem I am facing is that when `TextView` used to display 16 sp text, remains "big" when re-used to display 12 sp text.

Have tried to `invalidate()`/`requestLayout()`/`forceLayout()` but it did not work. How do I force the `TextView` to display itself properly?